# What display size and resolution is good for reading PDF in double page view?

Tags: display, pdf

I have currently 17" in SXGA, and I used to read a lot of PDF files. What I want pages should be displayed in book view (double full page). Is 24" in 1900 x 1200 enough to display PDF, since in this mode while keeping the text big enough to be read from about 60 CM or more ? If not, what sizes and resolutions are the best suitable?

Comment: Meta discussion: [Make the question about display screen on-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13363/301042)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display your documents at real size, you'll need a monitor with a width of more than 42-43 cm (for A4 and Letter pages).

I have a 21.5 inches 1920x1080 monitor with a width of 48 cm and it is good for this. The height of 27 cm is however not enough for the 29.7 cm of A4.

> keeping the text big enough to be read from about 60cm

That depends a lot on the text size and font.

> Is a 24" in 1900x1200 enough

I would say yes. It would have a width of 20 inches (51 cm).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended distance between your eyes and screen is an arm length.

1. The arm length is around 60 cm (25 inch). At that distance, the x-height for easy readability is 3 mm (2 "sub-inch").
2. The page width of a textbook is usually around 20 cm (8''). To get a 3 mm x-height of text, the page needs to be zoomed at 200%, or 40 cm (16'') *width*. **A 18'' monitor can satisfy this.**

**Note:** my textbooks have one main column and a smaller column for note-taking, and I don't need double full page. So this doesn't answer OP's question, but it may help other visitors.

An example of such page design, taken from Strenberg, Cognitive Psychology:
[image]